# strapi database storage user cart

Tags: reactjs, strapi

Please tell me - how can I save the data of the user's basket of goods to the database in strapi, so that when the page is updated, the basket of goods does not disappear

I only found a way to save data in local storage, but I don't understand how I can save data in a database. for example : product page visit history, purchase history, etc.